# ui-grid: problems to access $scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a problem with my ui-grid setup.

There is one ui-grid with an expandable row template loading a html file containing another ui-grid.
In this "subgrid" there is another expandable row template with another html-file containing 3 divs and a third ui-grid.

It works fine and shows all data needed.
In the most inner (is that a word?) expandable row (that with the 3 divs and the third grid) I want to use some functions to show and hide data with ng-show and some crud actions to edit the content of the third ("subsubgrid") ui-grid.

Since functions in the scope are not directly accessible I added an appScopeProvider and put the function in the subGridScope.
Now the function is accessed (I checked it with an alert).

In the function I set some boolean variables (e.g. $scope.showcreate = true), the divs contain ng-show directives (ng-show="showcreate") to hide or show the content of the div.

I debugged the function in the subGridScope and it sets the right values in $scope.showxyz, but the div is not hidden when set to false.

Do I need to re-render the page to "see" the change?
Do I need to change the ng-show directive?
Is there any good tutorial explaining this problem?
How would I access the "CRUD" actions? Would grid.appScope.function work even if the scope is kinda "stacked"?

If you need any more information, just ask, I will provide you with all information needed.

Here is the code:
**app.js:**

```
    var alarmwesen = angular.module('alarmwesen', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.expandable']);
alarmwesen.controller('AlarmwesenCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', '$log', '$templateCache', 'i18nService', '$interval', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $http, $log, $templateCache, i18NService, $interval, uiGridConstants) {
        $http.get('/api/action1)
                                       .success(function (data) {
                                          $scope.Beauftragter = data;
                                       });
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            enableScrollbars : false,
            expandableRowTemplate: 'expandableRowTemplate.html',
            expandableRowHeight: 1400,
            rowHeight: 36,
            expandableRowScope: { subGridVariable: 'subGridScopeVariable' },
            enableFiltering: true,
            treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false,
            columnDefs: [
            { name: 'Trigraph',field:'ZeigeTrigraphen', width: '10%'  },
            { name: 'Titel', field: 'Titel' },
            ],
            onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
                $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
                gridApi.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged($scope, function(row) {
                    if (row.isExpanded) {
                        row.entity.subGridOptions = {
                            appScopeProvider: $scope.subGridScope,
                            enableScrollbars: false,
                            expandableRowTemplate: 'expandableRowTemplate2.html',
                            expandableRowHeight: 700,
                            enableFiltering: false,
                            expandableRowScope: { subGridVariable: 'subsubGridScopeVariable' },
                            columnDefs: [
                                { name: 'LfdAngabe', field:'LfdAngabe', width: '10%' },

                                { name: 'Text', field: 'Text' }],
                            onRegisterApi:function(gridapi) {
                                this.subgridApi = gridapi;
                                gridapi.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged($scope, function(row) {
                                    if (row.isExpanded) {
                                        row.entity.subsubGridOptions = {
                                        appScopeProvider: $scope.subGridScope,
                                            columnDefs: [
                                                { name: 'Durchführungsverantwortliche',width:'25%' }, { name: 'Auftrag' },
                                                { name: 'Aktionen', field: 'EinzelauftragId', width: '10%', cellTemplate: '<a  id="Details" ng-click = "grid.appScope.BearbeiteAuftrag(row.entity.EinzelauftragId)" class="btn btn-success" )"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"</a><a  id="Details" ng-click = "grid.appScope.LoescheAuftrag(row.entity.AuftragId)" class="btn btn-danger" )"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"</a>' }

                                            ]
                                        };
                                        $http.get('/api/action2')
                                            .success(function(data) {
                                                row.entity.subsubGridOptions.data = data;
                                            });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        };
                        $http.get('/api/action3?trigraph=' + row.entity.ZeigeTrigraphen)
                            .success(function(data) {
                                row.entity.subGridOptions.data = data;

                            });

                }

        });
    }
        };
        $scope.subGridScope = {
            NeuerAuftrag: function () {
              $scope.showcreate = true;
              $scope.showedit = false;
          $scope.showdelete = false;
                alert("Geht doch!");
            }
        };



$http.get('/api/AlarmwesenWebAPI/HoleAlle').then(function (resp) {
    $scope.gridOptions.data = resp.data;
    $log.info(resp);
});



    }]);
```

**html-files**

```
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="grid.appScope.NeuerAuftrag()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> &#160 Neuen Auftrag erstellen</button>
        <div class="well" ng-show="showcreate"> 
            <div class="well-header">Einzelauftrag erstellen</div>

            <form role="form" ng-submit="ErstelleEinzelauftrag()" ng-model="Einzelauftrag" name="einzelauftragcreate" id="einzelauftragcreate">
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" id="createEinzelauftragsId" class="" ng-model="Einzelauftrag.EinzelauftragsId" />
                    <input type="text" id="createAlarmkalenderId" class="" ng-model="Einzelauftrag.AlarmkalenderId" />
                    <input type="text" id="createAlarmmassnahmeTrigraph" class="" ng-model="Einzelauftrag.AlarmmassnahmeTrigraph" />
                    <input type="text" id="createEinzelmassnahmeLfdAngabe" class="" ng-model="Einzelauftrag.EinzelmassnahmeLfdAngabe" />

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="createBeauftragterId">Durchführungsverantwortlicher:</label>
                        <select name="editBeauftragterId" id="createBeauftragterId"
                                ng-options="Beauftragter.Bezeichnung for Beauftragter in $scope.Beauftragter track by $scope.Beauftragter.BeauftragterId"
                                ng-model="$scope.Beauftragter.BeauftragterId"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="createAuftragstext">Auftrag:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="createAuftragstext" ng-model="Einzelauftrag.Auftragstext"> </textarea>

                    </div>


                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Auftrag erstellen</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="well" ng-show="showedit">
            <div class="well-header">Einzelauftrag ändern</div>

            <form role="form" ng-submit="BearbeiteEinzelauftrag()" ng-model="Einzelauftrag" name="einzelauftragedit" id="einzelauftragedit">
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" id="editEinzelauftragsId" class="" ng-model="Einzelauftrag.EinzelauftragsId" />
                    <input type="text" id="editAlarmkalenderId" class="" ng-model="Einzelauftrag.AlarmkalenderId" />
                    <input type="text" id="editAlarmmassnahmeTrigraph" class="" ng-model="Einzelauftrag.AlarmmassnahmeTrigraph" />
                    <input type="text" id="editEinzelmassnahmeLfdAngabe" class="" ng-model="Einzelauftrag.EinzelmassnahmeLfdAngabe" />

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="editBeauftragterId">Durchführungsverantwortlicher:</label>
                        <select name="editBeauftragterId" id="editBeauftragterId"
                                ng-options="beauftragter.Bezeichnung for beauftragter in data.Beauftragter track by Beauftragter.BeauftragterId"
                                ng-model="data.beauftragter.BeauftragterId"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="editAuftragstext">Auftrag:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="editAuftragstext" ng-model="Einzelauftrag.Auftragstext"> </textarea>

                    </div>


                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Änderung speichern</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="well" ng-show="showdelete">
            <div class="well-header">Einzelauftrag löschen</div>

            <form role="form" ng-submit="LoescheEinzelauftrag()" ng-model="Einzelauftrag" name="einzelauftragdelete" id="einzelauftragdelete">
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" id="deleteEinzelauftragsId" class="" ng-model="Einzelauftrag.EinzelauftragsId" />
                    <input type="text" id="deleteAlarmkalenderId" class="" ng-model="Einzelauftrag.AlarmkalenderId" />
                    <input type="text" id="deleteAlarmmassnahmeTrigraph" class="" ng-model="Einzelauftrag.AlarmmassnahmeTrigraph" />
                    <input type="text" id="deleteEinzelmassnahmeLfdAngabe" class="" ng-model="Einzelauftrag.EinzelmassnahmeLfdAngabe" />

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="deleteBeauftragterId">Durchführungsverantwortlicher:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="deleteBeauftragterId" ng-model="Einzelauftrag.BeauftragterId">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="deleteAuftragstext">Auftrag:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="deleteAuftragstext" ng-model="Einzelauftrag.Auftragstext"> </textarea>

                    </div>


                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Auftrag löschen</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div ui-grid="row.entity.subsubGridOptions" style="height: 700px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to execute the method 'BearbeiteAuftrag' from 3rd Grid while clicking the hyperlink on second column. For that you can try the following changes.

1. On the 3rd Grid definition (row.entity.subsubGridOptions=), replace the line "appScopeProvider: $scope.subGridScope," with "appScopeProvider: $scope,"
2. Add the following function just after the "$scope.gridOptions =...."

```js
$scope.BearbeiteAuftrag = function (einzelauftragId){
alert(einzelauftragId);
//Add code for the logic here with the parameter einzelauftragId
};
```